# a line of numbers (python)

Tags: python

I'm not a programmer, I'm just starting to learn python 2.
I wanted to know how can I write a code in python 2 to get an input that consists a line of numbers seperated by space from the user and do operations with each number sepeately and print the output of each number, again, as a line of numbers seperated by space?

Comment: Hi Matin.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I understand you aren't a programmer by trade, but have you tried anything yet to get solution?  If you have, post what you've got and what issues you are having.  If you haven't maybe spend some time familiarizing yourself with Python.  A quick search on Google for something like "how to get user input in python" will turn up plenty of results to get you going.

Comment: alright, I should use raw_input. but how should I get a line of numbers and be able to do stuff to each of them, seperately?

Comment: Give a man a fish, feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish, feed him for life.  This link should give you a good understanding of something called `split()`.  Seems like it's right up the alley for what you want: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example will loop complete the action you were looking for, just replace the "+5" with the operation you want

```
userInput = raw_input("Enter Numbers:")#Get user input
seperateNumbers = userInput.split(" ")#Seperate data based off of spaces
numbersAfterOperations = []#Create a lsi to hold the values after operation applied
for i in range(0, len(seperateNumbers)): #loop throgh all values
    numbersAfterOperations.append(int(seperateNumbers[i]) + 5) #add new value

printedValue = ""
for i in range(0, len(numbersAfterOperations)):
    printedValue += str(numbersAfterOperations[i]) + " "
print printedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You will start with a string containing all your numbers, so you will have something like this:

```
line_of_num = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

You will have to split the elements of this string. You can do it using the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of the string class, using a space as separator. It will return a list of the items with your numbers, but you can't operate them as integers yet.

```
list_of_num = line_of_num.split(" ")
```

You can't operate them yet because the elements of your list are strings. Before operating them, you have to cast them into integers. You can do it using [list comprehentions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
list_of_int = [int(element) for element in list_of_num]
```

Then you can operate them using common operations through elements of a list. Finally, when you have the results, you can return them as a string separated by spaces using the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of the string class using a space as separator. The join method has as input an iterable (list, for example) of strings.

```
results = " ".join(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
```

Your resulted string will be something like "1 2 3 4 5".